# How to use custom previous/next link ?

Tags: pagination, html

I have this :

```
    <?php the_posts_pagination( array(
      'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
      'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    ) ); ?>
```

Which gives this output :

[image]

What I want is this :

[image]

How to do this using the_posts_pagination() please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this to output only links for previous and next pages:

```
<?php previous_posts_link ( 'Previous' ) ?>
<?php next_posts_link ( 'Next' ); ?>
```

Then add filters to your functions.php to add a class to each link:

```
function next_posts_link_css ( $content ) {
    return 'class="next"';
}
add_filter( 'next_posts_link_attributes', 'next_posts_link_css' );

function previous_posts_link_css ( $content ) {
    return 'class="prev"';
}
add_filter( 'previous_posts_link_attributes', 'previous_posts_link_css' );
```

Then style the `.next` and `.prev` links using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on next page and previous page links and inspect element (assuming you are using chrome). You will get to know the classes and then style as you like.